# WoW Spell ID Question from API

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to use the Blizzard Spell ID API to do something like this website does:

https://wow.gamepedia.com/Mage_abilities

However, the API doesn't return the class that uses that spell. So, just thinking about how I'd do it currently, I'd have to manually get every spell ID and figure out which class it belongs to. But there has to be an easier way, right?

So, my question is: Is there an easier way to do this? My problem would be solved if Blizzard included the class in their spell ID API, but that's not the case.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Spells are a lot more than mages spitting fire. Almost everything you do is a spell (mounting up, using the hearthstone, etc) and a lot of them are shared among classes or NPCs. That's why they're not tied to classes in the API.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Blizzard API does not provide a way to figure out which spells can be used by a class. As @dly stated in their comment, there is a reason why the developers did not make a spell belong to a class.

I believe the only way to figure this out is by datamining the client, or by using in-game addons to view spell IDs on the specific class you want to figure it out for. This is how websites like Wowhead have done it.

For example, Wowhead splits their spells up in 4 categories:

- Specialization abilities (class/spec spells)
- NPC abilities
- Uncategorized spells

The only way to "determine" these categories is by datamining the client data and figuring out where a certain spell ID is being used. These categories aren't even something that the client uses - it's something Wowhead has assigned to make them easy to separate.

Without an external site or tool like Wowhead, it's very hard to determine which ability is used by the class in question. For example, Bloodthirst has over 20 entries in the spells database!